# Incorrect if-else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I've been trying to write a function that will ask for a number between 1-11 and will randomly choose a number and will compare between them.
I can't figure out why no matter what number I type in (equals or smaller or bigger) it will always type the "Your number is less" message.

```
def loto():
    _number = int(input("Enter any number between 1-10: "))
    import random
    for x in range(1):
        print ("Python chose: " + str(random.randint(1,11)))
    if ("_number" == "random"):
        print ("You Won! :)")
    if ("_number" < "random"):
        print ("Your number is less")
    if ("_number" > "random"):
        print ("Your number is more")
    else:
        print ("You Lost :(")

loto()
```

I'm using Python 3.

Thanks:)

Comment: You are comparing strings, not variables.

Comment: You also need to use `elif`, not separate `if` statements. Otherwise, the `You Lost` message gets printed whenever `_number > random` is not true, instead of only whenever all of the three comparisons are not true.

Comment: but if I take "" off it will say: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'module'

Comment: While we're at it: why are you using `_number` instead of `number`, why do you have parentheses around your conditions, and why are you doing `for x in range(1):` which just loops once, setting `x` to 0, and never using `x`? You're making your code more complicated and harder to understand to no benefit.

Comment: That's because your code makes no sense. What is `_number == random` supposed to do? `_number` is a number, but `random` is a module.

Comment: You need to actually store the randomly generated number in a variable. If you just print the random number, how do you expect to compare it to the user input later?

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include part of the answer; that changes it into a different question.

Comment: Thank you, guys!! You all are awesome I got it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're comparing the strings `"_number"` and `"random"`. ASCIIbetically (or, rather, Unicoderifically), `"_number" < "random"`, because the `_` character is #95 and the `r` character is #114.

If you want to compare two variables, you just refer to the variables, not strings that happen to be the same as the names of those variables.

Your second problem is that `random` isn't your random number, it's the module you used to create that number. And, more seriously, you aren't storing that number anywhere—you're just converting it to a string to print it out and then throwing it away.

Your third problem is that you need to change those `if`s to `elif`s. Otherwise, the `You Lost` message gets printed whenever `_number > random` is not true, instead of only whenever all of the three comparisons are not true.

Putting that all together:

```
choice = random.randint(1,11)
for x in range(1):
    print ("Python chose: " + str(choice))
if (_number == choice):
    print ("You Won! :)")
elif (_number < choice):
    print ("Your number is less")
elif (_number > choice):
    print ("Your number is more")
else:
    print ("You Lost :(")
```

---

Of course there's no way to actually lose your game—one of the three conditions is always going to be true. (If you were using complex numbers, or floats including NaN, you could input a number that wasn't comparable in any way to the selected one, but you're not.)

---

While we're at it:

- There's no reason to name your variable `_number` instead of `number`.
- That `for x in range(1):` loop doesn't do anything useful—it loops exactly once, setting `x` to 0, which you never use.
- You don't need parentheses around your conditions.
- You shouldn't import modules in the middle of a function like that except in special cases where you need unusual things like lazy loading.
- You should follow PEP 8 style, or at least pick a consistent style to follow.
- It's simpler to just pass multiple arguments to `print`, or to use string formatting, than to manually convert things to strings and concatenate them.

So:

```
import random

def loto():
    number = int(input("Enter any number between 1-10: "))
    choice = random.randint(1, 11)
    print("Python chose:", choice)
    if number == choice:
        print("You Won! :)")
    elif number < choice:
        print("Your number is less")
    elif number > choice:
        print("Your number is more")
    else:
        print("You Lost :(")

loto()
```

Comment: @melpomene Yes, of course it is. But it's also not relevant to the problem. There are also a number of other things that can be improved that aren't relevant to the problem. That's why I first show the minimal changes to fix this, and then, separately, explain all of those improvements.

Comment: you awesome dude!

Answer (score 0):

You were comparing strings not variables, you need to remove quotes, and you not saved random number into a variable. The for loop is making one repetition only, you can remove it.
Update your cod like this:

```
import random
def loto():
    _number = int(input("Enter any number between 1-10: "))

    rand_number = random.randint(1,11) # can't had the same name as random
    if (_number == rand_number):
        print ("You Won! :)")
    elif (_number < rand_number):
        print ("Your number is less")
    elif (_number > rand_number):
        print ("Your number is more")
    else:
        print ("You Lost :(")

loto()
```